# validating input address,in flutter

Tags: flutter, geocoding

In my app, I have to take in a user address. The user needs to type in a valid address. How can I achieve this? Is there any library which can help me with the names of states, cities and street names? I would like to use autotype if possible. I read GeoCoding but I don't think it will help me as the user is not entering the address from the current location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flutter_google_places

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_places